# Export Microstrategy grid data in text format to a FTP server

Tags: web-services, export, microstrategy

Can anybody please let me know whether it is possible to export microstrategy grid data in text format to a FTP server (required access will be provided). If not directly, then can we use some kind of java coding/web services to achieve this. I don't want the process but want to understand whether this can be achieved or not?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve report results (and build a new report from scratch at that) via the SDK and from there you can process the data to your liking, i.e. transform & upload to a ftp-server.
Possibly easier would be to create a file-subscription and store the file to a specific directory where you automatically pick it up and deliver it to your ftp.

There might be other solutions as well, but Yes is the answer to the "Yes/No" part of your question.